# PostgreSQLでdumpファイルのインポートができない。

Tags: python, python3, postgresql, windows-10

Windows上でPostgreSQLにdumpファイルのインポートをしようとしたら、インポートできませんでした。
コマンドラインは次の通りです。

```
database=# \lo_import c:/database.backup
lo_import 16401
database=# \dt
            リレーション一覧
スキーマ |   名前   |    型    |  所有者
----------+----------+----------+----------
public   | products | テーブル | postgres
(1 行)
```

ただし、products データベースは、もともとあった1行のテーブルです。
また、pythonを使って次のようにしてもダメでした。

```
import psycopg2

connector = psycopg2.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port= '5432',
    database='postgres',
    user='postgres',
    password='*********',
)
cursor = connector.cursor()

sql = "pg_restore -d database2 c:/database.backup"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

何がわるいのでしょうか。
また、うまく行く方法が別にありましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \lo_import c:/database.backup

`\lo_import`はファイルをPostgreSQLのラージオブジェクトに保存するコマンドのため、
dumpファイルをリストアするためには利用できないようです。
(参考: [psql](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.5/html/app-psql.html))

> sql = "pg_restore -d database2 c:/database.backup"

また、`pg_restore`はSQLではなく、コマンドなのでコマンドプロンプトから利用しなければならないと思います。
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\バージョン番号\bin`などにコマンドは格納されていると思いますので、パスを通すか、格納ディレクトリへ移動するか、してから`pg_restore -d database2 c:/database.backup`を実行してみてください。

Comment: できました、ありがとうございました。